# Magento - Update the number of zero in currencies

Tags: magento, e-commerce, currency

I'm working on an e-commerce website. I have a problem with the currency used in my site. I use a currency with three zero after the point and magento uses only two zero after the point for all currencies. How to resolved my problem and update the third zero with the my currencies that i work with.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can find settings for currnecy numbers format here /lib/Zend/Locale/Data in .xml according to you locale (example - en.xml)

```
       <currencyFormats>
            <currencyFormatLength>
                <currencyFormat>
                    <pattern>¤#,##0.00;(¤#,##0.00)</pattern>
                </currencyFormat>
            </currencyFormatLength>
            <unitPattern count="one">{0} {1}</unitPattern>
            <unitPattern count="other">{0} {1}</unitPattern>
        </currencyFormats>
```

Here in pattern section you can add one more zero. Don't forget flush magento cache after provide this changes.

Comment: I add in the en.xml or in the file who use my currency. For example i use tunisian dinars, i will edit the ar_TN.xml or the global file en.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also found a magento extension that facilitates changing all currency format . Here is the link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html It's free, stable and usefull with all version.